# Why won't YUI 2 DataTables work in IE but DO work in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, yui, datatables

So I am using the YUI 2 data table widget and tabview component to display the results of multiple queries, which are all executed at the same time, in separate tabs with nice, styled, and sortable tables. Works great in FireFox.  In IE, it just displays the data in a simple HTML table markup that is generated server side with PHP, which actually serves as the DataSource for the datatable widget. All of my HTML is generated server side. Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  YAHOO.util.Event.onContentReady("ready14", function() {
 //Sets globals

 var dataSource= YAHOO.util.DataSource;
 var getIt = YAHOO.util.Dom.get;
 var dataType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_HTMLTABLE;
 var table =  YAHOO.widget.DataTable;
 var scroll = YAHOO.widget.ScrollingDataTable;
 var numbers= YAHOO.widget.DataTable.formatNumber;
 var strings = YAHOO.widget.DataTable.formatString;
 var dates = YAHOO.widget.DataTable.formatDate;

 var niceTables = function() {


            var myTabView = new YAHOO.widget.TabView("reportTables");
        var myColumnDefs =[
            {key:"Tactic",formatter:strings,sortable:true},
            {key:"Opt-In Count",formatter:numbers,sortable:true,        sortOptions:     defaultDir: table.CLASS_DESC }},
        ];
         var myColumnDefs2 =[
            {key:"Tactic",formatter:strings,sortable:true},
            {key:"Opt-In Count",formatter:numbers,sortable:true, sortOptions: { defaultDir: table.CLASS_DESC }},
        ];
        var myColumnDefs3 =[
            {key:"Lead Meta Data ID" },{key:"First Name",formatter:strings,sortable:true},{key:"Last Name",formatter:strings,sortable:true},{key:"Address"}, {key:"City",formatter:strings,sortable:true},{key:"State",formatter:strings,sortable:true},{key:"Zip",formatter:strings,sortable:true}, {key:"Email"},{key:"Phone"}, {key:"Gender",formatter:strings,sortable:true},
            {key:"DOB",formatter:dates,sortable:true},{key:"Lead Type",formatter:strings,sortable:true}, {key:"Lead Source"},{key:"LOB",formatter:strings,sortable:true},{key:"Client",formatter:strings,sortable:true},{key:"Rep Nbr",formatter:strings,sortable:true, sortOptions: { defaultDir: YAHOO.widget.DataTable.CLASS_DESC }},{key:"Duplicate",formatter:strings,sortable:true},{key:"Comments"}, {key:"Social Media Source",formatter:strings,sortable:true},{key:"Lead Ready",formatter:dates,sortable:true,},{key:"Lead Sent",formatter:dates,sortable:true, sortOptions: { defaultDir: YAHOO.widget.DataTable.CLASS_DESC }},{key:"Tactic Name",formatter:strings,sortable:true},{key:"Tactic Line Of Business ",formatter:strings,sortable:true},
        ];

                    var myColumnDefs4 =[
            {key:"Prize Type",formatter:strings,sortable:true },{key:"First Name",formatter:strings,sortable:true},{key:"Last Name",formatter:strings,sortable:true},{key:"Address"},{key:"City", sortable:true}, {key:"State",formatter:strings,sortable:true},{key:"Zip",formatter:strings,sortable:true},{key:"Email"}, {key:"Phone"}, {key:"Play Date",formatter:dates,sortable:true, sortOptions: { defaultDir:table.CLASS_DESC }},
           ];
        var myColumnDefs5 =[
            {key:"Prize Type",formatter:strings,sortable:true },
            {key:"Prize Type Count",formatter:numbers,sortable:true, sortOptions: { defaultDir: table.CLASS_DESC }},
        ];
        var myColumnDefs6 =[
            {key:"Lead Source",formatter:strings,sortable:true},
            {key:"Dupe Count",formatter:numbers,sortable:true, sortOptions: { defaultDir:table.CLASS_DESC }},
        ];
        var myColumnDefs7 =[
            {key:"Guitar Type",formatter:strings,sortable:true },
            {key:"Count",formatter:numbers,sortable:true, sortOptions: { defaultDir: table.CLASS_DESC }},
        ];
        var myColumnDefs8 =[
            {key:"Tactic",formatter:strings,sortable:true },
            {key:"Opt-In Count",formatter:numbers,sortable:true, sortOptions: { defaultDir: table.CLASS_DESC }},
        ];
        var myColumnDefs9 =[
            {key:"Tactic",formatter:strings,sortable:true },
            {key:"Opt-In Count",formatter:numbers,sortable:true, sortOptions: { defaultDir: table.CLASS_DESC }},
        ];
                    var myColumnDefs10 =[
            {key:"Concert ID" },{key:"Artist" },{key:"Concert City" },{key:"Concert State" },{key:"Concert Date" },{key:"Entry Deadline" },{key:"Lead Meta Data ID" }, {key:"First Name"},
             {key:"Last Name"}, {key:"Address"},{key:"City"},{key:"State"},{key:"Zip"},{key:"Email"},{key:"Phone"},{key:"Lead Type"},{key:"Lead Source"},   {key:"LOB"},{key:"Client"},{key:"Rep Nbr"}, {key:"Duplicate"},,
        ];

        //get the YUI DataSource for each table
        var myDataSource =  new dataSource(getIt("optins"));
        myDataSource.responseType = dataType;
        myDataSource.responseSchema = {
            fields: ["Tactic","Opt-In Count"]
        };
        var myDataSource2 =  new dataSource(getIt("optTotal"));
        myDataSource2.responseType = dataType;
        myDataSource2.responseSchema = {
            fields: ["Tactic","Opt-In Count"]
        };
        var myDataSource3 =  new dataSource(getIt("optInReport"));
        myDataSource3.responseType = dataType;
        myDataSource3.responseSchema = {
            fields: ["Lead Meta Data ID","First Name","Last Name","Address","City","State","Zip","Email","Phone",
                    "Gender","DOB","Lead Type","Lead Source","LOB","Client","Rep Nbr","Duplicate","Comments","Social Media Source","Lead Ready","Lead Sent","Tactic Name","Tactic Line Of Business",]
        };
        var myDataSource4 =  new dataSource(getIt("spinWinners"));
        myDataSource4.responseType = dataType;
        myDataSource4.responseSchema = {
            fields: ["Prize Type","Band","First Name","Last Name","Address","City","State","Zip","Email","Phone","Play Date",]
        };
         var  myDataSource5 =  new dataSource(getIt("prizes"));
         myDataSource5.responseType = dataType;
         myDataSource5.responseSchema = {
            fields: ["Prize Type","Prize Type Count"]
        };
         var  myDataSource6 =  new dataSource(getIt("dupeCount"));
        myDataSource6.responseType = dataType;
        myDataSource6.responseSchema = {
            fields: ["Lead Source","Dupe Count"]
        };
         var myDataSource7 =  new dataSource(getIt("guitarType"));
        myDataSource7.responseType = dataType;
        myDataSource7.responseSchema = {
            fields: ["Guitar Type","Count"]
        };
         var myDataSource8 =  new dataSource(getIt("guitarTactic"));
        myDataSource8.responseType = dataType;
        myDataSource8.responseSchema = {
            fields: ["Tactic","Opt-In Count"]
        };
        var myDataSource9 =  new dataSource(getIt("OptInsSent"));
        myDataSource9.responseType = dataType;
        myDataSource9.responseSchema = {
            fields: ["Tactic","Opt-In Count"]
        };
          var myDataSource10 =  new dataSource(getIt("ticketEntries"));
       myDataSource10.responseType = dataType;
       myDataSource10.responseSchema = {
           fields: ["Concert ID","Artist","Concert City","Concert State","Concert Date","Entry Deadline","Lead Meta Data ID","First Name","Last Name","Address","City","State","Zip","Email","Phone",
                 "Lead Type","Lead Source","LOB","Client","Rep Nbr","Duplicate",]
        };


                        new table("table1", myColumnDefs, myDataSource);            
                        new table("table3", myColumnDefs2, myDataSource2);          
                        new scroll("table4", myColumnDefs3, myDataSource3,{width:"118em", height:"53em"});          
                        new table("table6", myColumnDefs4, myDataSource4);          
                        new table("table7", myColumnDefs5,  myDataSource5);         
                        new table("table8", myColumnDefs6, myDataSource6);          
                        new table("table10", myColumnDefs7, myDataSource7);
                        new table("table11", myColumnDefs8, myDataSource8);         
                        new table("table12", myColumnDefs9, myDataSource9);                       
                        new scroll("table13", myColumnDefs10, myDataSource10,{width:"118em", height:"53em"});
            }();











        return {

        };
```

});

Comment: (I have removed the "PHP" tag because it is irrelevant here)
@Phill For the first time I miss a down-vote feature for comments. He uses a library that is designed for x-browser dev. Knowing YUI2 to be able to help would be nice, and actually (serioulsy) referring to the question even more so.
To mbastian05: Breaking the example down to a minimum required to show the problem would be NICE - I'm sure we don't need all those DSs and (S)DTs? Because I'm sooo lazy, scrolling, especially horizontally, is tough work :)

Comment: ...oh and maybe include a (minimal) example for the generated HTML that the DT consumes. While I'm at it, you keep quiet about the exact version of YUI2 being used. And (minor issue) from the example code I cannot see the point of the "return {}" at the end - seems there's more context? As it is it seems to be returned into onContentReady which does not hurt but is useless. Also see no point in niceTables, nothing is returned, why not just run the code without placing it in the function, which executes immediately returning nothing - which is assigned to the var?

Comment: Also, have you checked which parts of your script are actually run, if there are any errors, and/or tried to turn on YUI2-debugging for the DTs? Tried a static HTML file with one of the generated tables that would not work, and then let a YUI2 DT loose on that HTML, manually in the console possibly (F12 opens dev. tools in IE, which includes a console - which IE, by the way?) Because it sounds like the DT doesn't even get started being created. Why debugging have you done? And you asked 7 questions and ACCEPTED NOT A SINGLE ANSWER???

Comment: Morre---I have been away for a few days so I haven't had a chance to declare a solution. So great way to be a jerk. Some of us have families and other commitments that we have to take care of.  I am not on  a computer 24/7, so that is why I haven't yet answered back on here.  Also, "7 different questions"???? I asked one.  Why won't this work in IE? Can you not read?  As for your static HTML solution----tried that.  I am not an idiot. I know where the developer tools are in IE.  As for including the whole piece of code...

Comment: Well, since I couldn't figure out what was going on, and figured it could be the smallest issue, I would post the whole code so that anyone kind enough to help would be able to see everything.  As for the pieces you deem "not necessary", fine, maybe they aren't, but since that has no bearing on the question I asked, why make it an issue.  Also who are you talking to in your first post? @phil? I see no post from anyone of that name.  If you are trying to help I appreciate it, but you should possibly think about how you may come across.

Comment: Offering an actual solution to the question I asked would be nice too. Instead of just criticizing me.

Comment: Oh, apparently I did need all those DT's and DS's since that ended up being where the issue was.

Comment: No, ONE would have been enough. Give the SMALLEST example possible for debugging. You did not do ANY work, and you don't acknowledge how much time *I* spent, instead you complain that I did not solve your issue for you!? Go away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have trailing commas in your objects/arrays.  IE chokes on trailing commas.

```
var breaksIE = ['trailing', 'comma', '=>', ]; // boom
```

Comment: Someone paid attention - dear mbastian05, by the way, you are supposed to declare this (or a) correct response a "solution".

Comment: Some things not even YUI can fix :)

Comment: Thank you so much Luke! That did the trick.  I should have thought about that but I was drawing a blank.  I appreciate it greatly!